# Difference between two simple functions in Swift

Tags: swift, function

I am currently studying Swift and I am wondering what is the difference between these two functions, and which is the most correct one?

```
func sayName (name: String) {
  println("Name is, \(name)") 
}


func sayNewName (name: String) -> String {
   return "Name is, + name"
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to implement...The first is a println comman...which returns nothing , but will print the the output : Name is , "parameter name".
Second one will return String value..but will not use the parameter!

Comment: Why isn't the second one using the parameter? Can't I write sayNewName("Alex") ? Isn't "Alex" the parameter?

Comment: use return "Name is, \\(name)"

Comment: In your second example you probably mean: `return "Name is, " + name`

Answer (score 1):

The first prints a line to standard output. It takes a parameter, `name`, of type `String`.

The second one explicitly declares both a return type (of type `String`) and also returns a value that can be used by any subsequent functions, etc.

There is no "most correct one" in this case, they just serve different purposes.

In other words, in the first function, you can't "do" anything with its return value. It is simply a function whose purpose is in its side effects, whereas the second function returns a value that can be used.

Comment: @JoshBeam sorry downvote accidently was by me. was better answer then mine, upvoted, fixed the mistake

Comment: @DanielKrom, ah okay thanks for the clarification! No problem at all!